# Removing last letter from string s = s.substring(0, s.length()-1); + setText works only sometimes

Tags: java, android, string, char

I'm making a keyboard made of buttons. Everythink works fine except the delete button. It works sometimes, sometimes I have to press it five times, sometimes 12. If I replace  s = s.substring(0, s.length()-1); for something like s = s +"whatever"; it works perfectly fine.

```
    public void onClickKeyboard (View view){


    if (view.getTag().equals("delete")){

                s = s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
                preguntaView.setText(s);

    } else if (view.getTag().equals("space")) {
        s = s + " ";
        preguntaView.setText( s.toString());

    } else if (!view.getTag().equals("delete") && !view.getTag().equals("space")){
        s = s + view.getTag().toString();
        preguntaView.setText( s.toString());

    }
```

EDIT : I tried to replace the substring with this with the same result, so I guess the problem is in the setText.

```
           preguntaView.setText(preguntaView.getText().toString().substring(0, preguntaView.getText().length()-1));
```

EDIT: If i log out the string s before and after the cut I get this:

```
02-02 12:59:33.030 16495-16495/com.example.root.exercicis I/here: v����������������������aaaagt
02-02 12:59:33.030 16495-16495/com.example.root.exercicis I/here: v����������������������aaaag
```

Comment: Try this: s = s.substring(0, s.length()-2);

Comment: I did, it happens the same, but weirdly sometimes it removes one char sometimes 2

Comment: What about `int len = s.length()-1; s = s.substring(0, len);` ?

Comment: I tried it, with the exact same result.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following. I have tried it in my local code and it is working.

```
if(view.getTag().equals("delete")){
    String data = preguntaView.getText().toString();
    if (data.length() > 0) {
        data = data.substring(0, data.length() - 1);
    }
    preguntaView.setText(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the same happens. I'm reading this now: https://tekeye.uk/android/examples/ui/android-app-text-not-updating It looks like setText can be problematic sometimes in Android

Comment: You can make a debug point before set text or print in logcat to check if the substring method is working or not. If that method is working then surely there is some issue with setText method.

Comment: OK this is what I get when I log out the string s before and after the chopping:
02-02 12:59:33.030 16495-16495/com.example.root.exercicis I/here: v����������������������aaaagt
02-02 12:59:33.030 16495-16495/com.example.root.exercicis I/here: v����������������������aaaag

Comment: As you can see, print statement can confirm that your last character from string value is removed. So there is definately something wrong going on with setText.

Comment: 02-02 13:08:34.519 19549-19549/com.example.root.exercicis I/log: Yo tengo un perro
    _____hfhe����������������������e����������������������e������������������

This is the data output with Dhaval code, the delete code actually works, it deletes this ? simbols and when it reaches the actual letter it deletes it